# how to cache html5 File(UIWebView)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I use the UIWebView to load the URL which is a HTML5 application.
What I want to do is cache the HTML file,when there is no net connection,it load the cache.
when the connection can be use,it load the URL again to see if there has new data

Comment: You might want to have a look at the HTML 'offline app'
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
#define APP_PATH_HTML_PAGES_CACHE [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"html_pages_cache"]

- (void)setUrlString:(NSString *)urlString{
    if (![_urlString isEqualToString:urlString]) {
        NSURL *url = nil;
        _urlString = urlString;
        NSString *fileName = [self fileNameFromUrl:_urlString];
        if(isInternetConnected){//load page and store on file system
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlString];
            [self downloadPageWithName:fileName andUrl:url];//download to cache
        }else{
            //network is not available, check for cached file
            if ([self isFileExistInCacheDirectory:fileName]) {
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[APP_PATH_HTML_PAGES_CACHE stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
            }
        else {
            //TODO: show offline/error alert
        }
    }
    //load local or remote page
    // here url can point to local file or web page
    NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    //to be sure that view components did initialized.
    if ([self view]) {
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];
    }
}


- (void)downloadPageWithName:(NSString*)fileName andUrl:(NSURL*)url
{
  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self checkIsCacheDirectoryExistOrCreate];`

    NSString *filePath = [APP_PATH_HTML_PAGES_CACHE stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Download: %@ -> %@", url.absoluteString, filePath);
});
```

}

Comment: how to use urlString?For example,when I start the application first time,it cache the first page,then I terminate the application.(the urlString has been destroyed)And then I start the application again,if the first page has change,it load the url again,or it just load the cache

Comment: Provided piece of code caches page on file system if network connection available and loads page from file system if no internet.